# Using Google Places Autocomplete with dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?csw=1) tutorial to implement Google Places Autocomplete. However, this only works well with existing statically defined text field. In my test app, I have dynamically added text field whereby user clicks on a button to add more text field.

```
<input maxlength="40" name="Point[location][]" id="Point_location" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
<input maxlength="40" name="Point[location][]" id="Point_location2" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
    var location = $("input[id^=Point_location]")[0];
    var autocompleteLocation = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(location, options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteLocation, 'place_changed', function () {
        var placeLocation = autocompleteLocation.getPlace();
    });
</script>
```

I can't seem to get the autocomplete to work any existing input with the id Point_location or input that has just been added.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be easier to answer when you had posted the code that creates the clone too.

I guess you are simply cloning the input, that will no work.  You must create a new Autocomplete-instance for each input:

```
//create the clone
  var clone=$(location).clone(false).val('').appendTo('body');
//apply Autocomplete
  var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(clone[0]);
//apply listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(ac, 'place_changed', function () {
    var placeLocation = this.getPlace();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Yes you are right, the input must be there to create a new autocomplete instance.